# Условный рендеринг React

Tags: reactjs

как я могу отрисовывать компонент Mycomp в зависимости от кликов на первый или второй div?

```
import "./header.css"
import Mycomp from "../test1";
function Header() {
    let isActive = false;
function fun1() {
isActive = true;
}
function fun2() {
isActive = false;
}
        return (
            <div>
                <div
                    className="header-div">
                    <div className="header-button" onClick={fun1}></div>
                    <div className="header-button" onClick={fun2}></div>
                </div>

                <Mycomp isActive={isActive}/>

            </div>
        )
    }

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно создавать `state`, а не просто переменную, так как рендер происходит после изменения стейта. В вашем случае после нажатия на кнопку будет меняться значение переменной `isActive`, но при этом перерендериваться ничего не будет.

Создание `state` с помощью хука `useState`:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
```

2. Так как функционал простой, можно не создавать дополнительных функций, а использовать сеттер (`setIsActive`) в `onClick`:

```
<div onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>div 1</div>
<div onClick={() => setIsActive(false)}>div 2</div>
```

но можно и написать такие функции, примерно так:

```
const setTrue = () => {
  setIsActive(true);
};

const setFalse = () => {
  setIsActive(false);
};
```

в таком случае, нужно будет навесить их на кнопки в `onClick`:

```
<div onClick={setTrue}>div 1</div>
<div onClick={setFalse}>div 2</div>
```

**< Header />**

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";
import MyComp from "./MyComp";

const Header = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>div 1</div>
      <div onClick={() => setIsActive(false)}>div 2</div>

      {isActive ? <MyComp /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**< MyComp />**

```js
import { React } from "react";

const MyComp = () => {
  return <div>MyComp</div>;
};

export default MyComp;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, но вы не могли бы пояснить смысл вот этой строки?
`const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);`
 isActive принимает значение setIsActive(true) или setIsActive(false)?

Comment: да, *isActive принимает значение setIsActive(true) или setIsActive(false)* - это так. `setIsActive` это сеттер, с помощью которого меняется значение `isActive`. Напрямую `isActive` менять нельзя, тоесть так делать нельзя: `isActive = true`. (можете почитать про хук useState подробнее)

Comment: @mishmish если вас устраивает ответ, то можете закрыть вопрос, слева от ответа